# Bind Focus Out event on GridView dynamic asp:TextBox using Update Pannel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, updatepanel

I have a grid view in an Update Panel, the grid has one column which contains asp:textbox. I want to bind and trigger asyncAutoPostBackTrigger on focus out of textboxes which are dynamically generated. I have the following Code

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
<asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-customized table-layout-fixed col-sm-offset-2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvLicense_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="word-wrap-break" HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" runat="server">Title</label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="word-wrap-break" HeaderText="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Title" Text='<%# Bind("vCertType") %>' OnTextChanged="Code_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="word-wrap-break" HeaderText="Add">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <button type="button" id="btnAddLicense" runat="server" class="btn btn-success-o">+</button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="<%=Bind(txtLicense.ClientID) %>"   EventName="" />
</Triggers>
```

The problem breakdown

- Bind Event on focus out in javascript
- Go to code behind get the value and save to DB

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<Triggers>` node, and add `AutoPostBack="true"` to the TextBox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Title" Text='<%# Bind("vCertType") %>' OnTextChanged="Code_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in code behind you can cast the sender back to a TextBox and get it's value.

```
protected void Code_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alertMe", "alert('" + tb.Text + "')", true);

    //save to database
}
```